# PDFBox - Saving a page as SVG format

Tags: java, pdfbox, batik

I'm trying to save each page of a given PDF document as an SVG file. Information on the topic seems scarce, in comparison to SVG to PDF which is quite popular.

Is there a simple way to do this using PDFBox, Batik or any combination of standard library features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code that saves all pages of the PDF, I probably have it from here or [from batik itself](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/svg-generator.html).

```
try (PDDocument pdfboxDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(dir, PDFFILE)))
{
    PDFRenderer r = new PDFRenderer(pdfboxDocument);
    for (int i = 0; i < pdfboxDocument.getNumberOfPages(); ++i)
    {
        String svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        DOMImplementation impl = GenericDOMImplementation.getDOMImplementation();
        Document myFactory = impl.createDocument(svgNS, "svg", null);
        SVGGeneratorContext ctx = SVGGeneratorContext.createDefault(myFactory);
        ctx.setEmbeddedFontsOn(true);
        SVGGraphics2D g2d = new SVGGraphics2D(ctx, true);
        r.renderPageToGraphics(i, g2d);
        String filename = "test-" + (i + 1) + ".svg";
        try (Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, filename)), "UTF-8"))
        {
            g2d.stream(out, true);
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml excerpt:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-svggen</artifactId>
        <version>${batik.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-codec</artifactId>
        <version>${batik.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-dom</artifactId>
        <version>${batik.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox-app</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```